# Custom Linked List using Nodes

Tags: java, list

I am having a hard time working with Linked List/Nodes, I basically have to create my own Linked List in Java using only nodes.

This is what I have to make:

> ```
>               -----                   -----           -----
>      head -->|  B  |---------------->|  D  |-------->|  S  |
>               -----                   -----           -----
>                |                        |               |
>                |   -----     -----      |   -----       |   -------     -----
>                -->| Ben |-->| Bob |     -->| Dan |      -->| Sarah |-->| Sue |
>                    -----     -----          -----           -------     -----
> ```

**This is what I have so far:**

```
public class index {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Front = start of list
    nameNode head = null; 


    //head = add(head,"Bob");
    //head.next = add(head,"Cat"); 
    //head.next.next = add(head, "Dog"); 

    nameNode cNode = new nameNode("C", null); 
    nameNode bNode = new nameNode("B",cNode);
    nameNode aNode = new nameNode("A",bNode);


    System.out.println(aNode.next); 


}

// This adds nodes to front of list
public static nameNode add(nameNode head, String movie)
{
    nameNode temp = new nameNode(movie, null); 
    temp.next = head; 
    return temp; 
}

//Private node class that creates new nodes 
private static class nameNode {

    public String data;

    public nameNode next; 

    public nameNode(String data, nameNode next){
        this.data = data; 
        this.next = next; 
    }

    public String toString(){
        return data + ""; 
    }
  }
}
```

So what should i do to make a TOP list, and BOTTOM sublist via nodes. So my idea was to basically create a node for B, then link Ben and Bob together, which links to B. And then have B link to D and so on?

Also I am playing around with nodes, I think the way I am making them right now is correct? Is there another way to create an object automatically instead of me having to create the object my self?

What I want to be able to do is use the add method to basically create a new node...but I dont understand how really to do that, any hints on how I can do this?

Comment: check LinkedList implementation of Java

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you tell me how to do/view this? I am a novice at java and I am not 100% sure yet how to use the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList()

Comment: the diagram actually Looks more like a Map<List<String>> than a List. Or maybe a List<List<>>

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Singly linked list, A list of list, or what? If if is Singly linked list, why is your diagram showing sub-lists branching out from the main list? Since you have sub-lists, what you wanted is a list of list right??

Comment: I don't think a list of list is the correct implementation here, he is creating a linked list implementation from scratch, and as such, he will need to create his own linked list nodes. He needs the 'letter' list nodes to maintain 2 pointers, one to the next 'letter' node, and one to the first 'name' node in the sub list. The 'name' nodes should maintain a single pointer to the next 'name' node in the sub list. On that note, be very particular with how you name your node classes to make sure that you convey what each node actually does.

Answer (score -1):

Please find implementation of `LinkedList` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList)

What i have noticed in pictorial representation is that, each **node** is pointing to **data** as well as **next node**.

But your `nameNode` class only has a next pointer. You might have to use another reference as used in `LinkedList` class.

Also try to use Generics so that you can put any data.

Comment: Yes you can... in doubly linked list one points to prev and other points to next. Similarly you can have more than 2 pointers as well :)

Comment: What did you mean by "each node is pointing to data as well as next node."?